# Ignoring null-Values for INT when filtering

Tags: c#

I´m writing an API in .net/C# and have a problem with the following service function:

```
public async Task<List<Item>> GetAsync(RequestParameters requestParameters) =>
        await _itemsCollection.Find(item => (item.item_description.Contains(requestParameters.FilterDescString) ||
                                            item.item_adddesc.Contains(requestParameters.FilterDescString)) &&
                                            item.item_id.Equals(requestParameters.FilterItemIdInt) &&
                                            item.item_amount.Equals(requestParameters.FilterAmountInt) &&
                                            item.item_width.Equals(requestParameters.FilterWidthInt) &&
                                            item.item_height.Equals(requestParameters.FilterHeightInt) &&
                                            item.item_weight.Equals(requestParameters.FilterWeightInt) &&
                                            item.item_aunumber.Contains(requestParameters.FilterAunumberString))
    .SortByDescending(i => i.item_id).Skip((requestParameters.PageNumber)* requestParameters.PageSize).Limit(requestParameters.PageSize)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here are non-null-values neccessary for all filters, but null values should be ignored in query. How can I achieve that? Regards

Edit:

If I have no value for any of that integers I need kind of a wildcard. Here is my model:

```
public class RequestParameters
{
    const int MaxPageSize = 50;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    private int _pageSize = 25;
    private string _filterDescString = "";
    private string _filterAunumberString = "";
    private int? _filterItemIdInt = null;
    private int? _filterAmountInt = null;
    private int? _filterWidthInt = null;
    private int? _filterHeightInt = null;
    private int? _filterWeightInt = null;

    public int PageSize
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageSize;
        }
        set
        {
            _pageSize = (value > MaxPageSize) ? MaxPageSize : value;
        }
    }

    public string FilterDescString
    {
        get
        {
            return _filterDescString;
        }
        set
        {
            _filterDescString = (value != null) ? value : _filterDescString;
        }
    }

    public string FilterAunumberString
    {
        get
        {
            return _filterAunumberString;
        }
        set
        {
            _filterAunumberString = (value != null) ? value : _filterAunumberString;
        }
    }

    public int? FilterItemIdInt
    {
        get
        {
            return _filterItemIdInt;
        }
        set
        {
            _filterItemIdInt = (value != null) ? value : _filterItemIdInt;
        }
    }

    public int? FilterAmountInt
    {
        get
        {
            return _filterAmountInt;
        }
        set
        {
            _filterAmountInt = (value != null) ? value : _filterAmountInt;
        }
    }

    public int? FilterWidthInt
    {
        get
        {
            return _filterWidthInt;
        }
        set
        {
            _filterWidthInt = (value != null) ? value : _filterWidthInt;
        }
    }

    public int? FilterHeightInt
    {
        get
        {
            return _filterHeightInt;
        }
        set
        {
            _filterHeightInt = (value != null) ? value : _filterHeightInt;
        }
    }

    public int? FilterWeightInt
    {
        get
        {
            return _filterWeightInt;
        }
        set
        {
            _filterWeightInt = (value != null) ? value : _filterWeightInt;
        }
    }
}
```

The initial call looks like this, the user can add various combinations of that string and int filters:

```
https://localhost:7010/api/Items?PageNumber=0&PageSize=25&FilterDescString=&FilterAunumberString=&FilterAmountInt=null&FilterWidthInt=null&FilterHeightInt=null&FilterWeightInt=null&FilterItemIdInt=null
```

The initial call and all calls that have at least a value for all of the integers return an empty array.

Comment: Do you mean `int?` ?

Comment: Please add more details to your question, and ideally post a sample that we can all copy/paste that reproduces the issue. It's not clear if you're taking in strings that represent numbers and you want to ignore (or fail on) null values, or if there are nullable ints in the input that you want to ignore, or something else.i

Answer (score 0):

I proceeded with a solution that uses FilterDefinitions on the mongodb thats connected with my API. Filtering for STRINGS works fine, but on filtering INT I get an empty array. Here is my solution:

```
public static FilterDefinition<Item> ParamsToFilter(RequestParameters requestParameters)
    {
        var builder = Builders<Item>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestParameters.FilterDescString))
        {
            var descFilter = builder.Regex(i => i.item_description, requestParameters.FilterDescString);
            filter &= descFilter;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestParameters.FilterAddDescString))
        {
            var addDescFilter = builder.Regex(i => i.item_adddesc, requestParameters.FilterAddDescString);
            filter &= addDescFilter;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestParameters.FilterAunumberString))
        {
            var aunumberFilter = builder.Regex(i => i.item_aunumber, requestParameters.FilterAunumberString);
            filter &= aunumberFilter;
        }
        if (requestParameters.FilterItemIdInt != null)
        {
            var itemIdFilter = builder.Eq(i => i.item_id, requestParameters.FilterItemIdInt);
            filter &= itemIdFilter;
        }
        if (requestParameters.FilterAmountInt != null)
        {
            var itemAmountFilter = builder.Eq(i => i.item_amount, requestParameters.FilterAmountInt);
            filter &= itemAmountFilter;
        }
        if (requestParameters.FilterWidthInt != null)
        {
            var itemWidthFilter = builder.Eq(i => i.item_width, requestParameters.FilterWidthInt);
            filter &= itemWidthFilter;
        }
        if (requestParameters.FilterHeightInt != null)
        {
            var itemHeightFilter = builder.Eq(i => i.item_height, requestParameters.FilterHeightInt);
            filter &= itemHeightFilter;
        }
        if (requestParameters.FilterWeightInt != null)
        {
            var itemWeightFilter = builder.Eq(i => i.item_weight, requestParameters.FilterWeightInt);
            filter &= itemWeightFilter;
        }

        return filter;
    }
```

This is a static method that just adds a filter to the FilterDefinition if there a non-null or non-empty filtervalue for the specific column in the db.

```
public async Task<List<Item>> GetAsync(RequestParameters requestParameters)
    {
        var filters = ParamsToFilter(requestParameters);
        return await _itemsCollection.Find(filters).SortByDescending(i => i.item_id).Skip((requestParameters.PageNumber) * requestParameters.PageSize).Limit(requestParameters.PageSize).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Later I use the given filters in the GetAsync() method with Find(). Regards